# Specify an external CSS file to use in an URL

Tags: php, css, printing

I have a external CSS file that is printer friendly and when user clicks on a link I want it to open in a new window/tab using the printer friendly CSS file.

Is there a way to do this with PHP? Was thinking along the lines of calling the URL with php and then create a new link for them to click on that uses the printer css.

Declared the print CSS file on the webpage when user using a browser chooses to print it uses it.  But I want the user to be able to view the page in print view themselves.

Comment: Just use a GET parameter and add a <link> tag when it is present?

Answer (score 4):

Page with ***printer unfriendly*** `CSS` file:

```
<a href="friendlycss.php?clicked=yes">Click me</a>
```

Page with ***printer friendly*** `CSS` file:

```
if(isset($_GET['clicked']){
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="link_to_sheet"></link>';
}
```

Or, the two pages can be identical and you can set the link to call the current page:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['clicked']){
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="link_to_sheet"></link>';
    }
?>
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?clicked=yes" />
```

That's all there is to it

Comment: just tried that did not work for me, will I need to set the yourpage.php for each page or will the get command get it?

Comment: @Damien-Data I don't understand your question. You just set the `href` of the `<a>` tag to go wherever you want it to go. It could link to the *current* page if you wanted it to.

Comment: do I need two copies of the same file, i.e. map.php and mapprint.php

Comment: or can map.php be opened in a new window/tab but use print.css rather than site.css

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['clicked']){
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css"></link>';
    }
?>
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?clicked=yes" />
</body>
</html>

Comment: I get an error when I try and run the page just won't display anything